# Dynamic MySql query that will return results X times a day

Tags: mysql, timer, division

I'm trying to wrap my head around this at the request of our CEO, we have a CRON script that talks to our database table every hour, this table only contains TWO rows, one for an output value, on for `times per day returned`. I am running this once an hour for 24 hours a day. The table looks like the below.

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| times | int(2)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| value | char(64)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am trying to create a query, that will return the `value`, X `times` a day,
so lets say...

```
INSERT INTO table
  (times, value) 
VALUES
  (1, 'Value 1'),
  (4, 'Value 2'),
  (9, 'Value 3');
```

I would expect to return `Value 1` once in a 24 hours period, `Value 2` four times in a 24 hour period, and `Value 3` nine times. since 9 is NOT divisible by 24, we can use floor() or ceil() or round(), doesn't matter as long as it is returned 9 times in a 24 hour period.

I'm having trouble even visualizing this query, much less implementing it =/

I'll post stuff I'm trying out as I get it working ....

**UPDATE**

This will give me hours to run it looks like

`SELECT (24 / times) AS hours FROM table;`

```
+---------+
|  hours  |
+---------+
| 24.0000 |
|  6.0000 |
|  2.6667 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create a separate table with 24 rows, one for each hour of the day, and include whether the particular Value should be returned in that hour?  Then join to that instead of trying to calculate something.

Like:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|Hr of day    |Run Value 1|Run Value 2|Run Value 3|
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1:00am     |    1      |    0      |    1      |
|  2:00am     |    1      |    0      |    0      |
|  3:00am     |    1      |    0      |    0      |
|  4:00am     |    1      |    0      |    1      |
|  5:00am     |    1      |    0      |    0      |
|  6:00am     |    1      |    1      |    0      |
|  ...
```